# How to Decode an Enum of Structs in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, enumeration, decodable

Apologies for the long question.

I am using [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) to store online data and have a current structure like the below;

```
{
  "activities": { 
    "mG47rRED9Ym4dkXinXrN": {
      "createdAt": 1234567890,
      "activityType": {
        "title": "Some Title"
      }
    },
    "BF3jhINa1qu9kia00BeG": {
      "createdAt": 1234567890,
      "activityType": {
        "percentage": 50,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using JSON Decodable Protocol to retrieve the data.  I have a main struct of;

```
struct Activity: Decodable {
    let documentID: String
    let createdAt: Int
    let activityType: ActivityType
}
```

this struct holds the mandatory data such as createdAt & documentID (i.e. "mG47rRED9Ym4dkXinXrN"). Depending upon the data nested inside "activityType" it should return one of two structs listed below;

```
struct NewGoal: Decodable {
    let title: String
}

struct GoalAchieved: Decodable {
    let percentage: Double
}
```

I am doing this with decodable enumeration;

```
enum ActivityType: Decodable {
    case newGoal(NewGoal)
    case goalAchieved(GoalAchieved)
}

extension ActivityType {

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case activityType
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        if let value = try? values?.decode(GoalAchieved.self, forKey: .activityType) {
            self = .goalAchieved(value)
            return
        }

        if let value = try? values?.decode(NewGoal.self, forKey: .activityType) {
            self = .newGoal(value)
            return
        }

        throw DecodingError.decoding("Cannot Decode Activity")
    }
}
```

When using the Activity struct as my array I am getting DecodingError. However, when using ActivityType as my array it will decode fine but it will not give access to the documentID & createdAt.  I cannot inherit Activity struct as it is non-protocol.  How would I go about structuring this, please?

Comment: Can you share the exact decode error message?

Comment: It’s the thrown error in my code “Cannot Decode Activity”

Comment: Does it say why? Maybe a key missing? Have you tried adding CodingKeys into the Activity struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was kind of tricky and fun to figure out. We have three complications that make this tough:

1. Variable coding keys
2. Coding keys which we also want to keep as values
3. Enumerated types with associated values

Here is my solution. It's a bit long. Let's start with your activity struct:

```
struct Activity {

    let documentId: String
    let createdAt: Int
    let activityType: ActivityType

}
```

Nice and easy. Now for that top-level decoding container:

```
struct Activities: Decodable {

    let activities: [Activity]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var activities: [Activity] = []

        let activitiesContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let container = try activitiesContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: VariableCodingKeys.self, forKey: .activities)
        for key in container.allKeys {
            let activityContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ActivityCodingKeys.self, forKey: key)
            let createdAt = try activityContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .createdAt)
            let activityType = try activityContainer.decode(ActivityType.self, forKey: .activityType)

            let activity = Activity(
                documentId: key.stringValue,
                createdAt: createdAt,
                activityType: activityType)

            activities.append(activity)
        }

        self.activities = activities
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case activities
    }

    private struct VariableCodingKeys: CodingKey {

        var stringValue: String
        var intValue: Int?

        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }

        init?(intValue: Int) {
            return nil
        }

    }

    private enum ActivityCodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case createdAt, activityType
    }

}
```

You'll notice a couple interesting points:

1. `ActivityCodingKeys` has only two of the fields in the `Activity` struct. That's because `documentId` is populated with the key of the nested container, which contains the rest of the data.
2. We have `VariableCodingKeys`, which let us work with any key/`documentId`.

Finally, we have the `ActivityType` enum:

```
enum ActivityType: Decodable {

    case newGoal(String), achievedGoal(Double)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let title = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title) {
            self = .newGoal(title)
        } else if let percentage = try? container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .percentage) {
            self = .achievedGoal(percentage)
        } else {
            throw DecodingError.keyNotFound(
                CodingKeys.title,
                DecodingError.Context(
                    codingPath: decoder.codingPath,
                    debugDescription: "Expected title or percentage, but found neither."))
        }
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case title, percentage
    }

}
```

One thing that surprised me as I was writing this up is that not all the CodingKeys have to be present for the decoder to generate the keyed container. I used that to combine `title` and `percentage` in one enum. Like your solution, I `try` decoding a certain key, see if it works, and move on if not.

I'll be the first to admit that this solution is **not** short. It does work, though, and it is kind of cool how it all works out. If you have any questions or ideas for making it more concise, let me know!

Comment: This works perfectly.  I hope I can expand on this with additional info in the structs :)